# Density plot based on time of the day

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate, density-plot

I've the following dataset:

https://app.box.com/s/au58xaw60r1hyeek5cua6q20byumgvmj

I want to create a density plot based on the time of the day. Here is what I've done so far:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library("lubridate")

timestamp_df$timestamp_time <- format(ymd_hms(hn_tweets$timestamp), "%H:%M:%S")

ggplot(timestamp_df, aes(timestamp_time)) + 
       geom_density(aes(fill = ..count..)) +
       scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"),labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

It gives the following error:
`Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`

If I convert that to `POSIXct`, it adds dates to the data.

**Update 1**

The following converted data to 'NA'

```
timestamp_df$timestamp_time <- as.POSIXct(timestamp_df$timestamp_time, format = "%H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC"
```

**Update 2**

Following is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: `timestamp_time` is of class... `character`? You have to coerce it using `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt`.

Comment: `timestamp_df$timestamp_time <- as.POSIXct(timestamp_df$timestamp_time, format = "%H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC")` made the data "NA"

Comment: Your `format` argument is incorrect. For next time, you might  consider providing your question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

df <- read.csv("data.csv") #given in OP
```

convert character to `POSIXct`

```
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",  tz = "UTC"))

library(hms)
```

extract hour and minute:

```
df$time <- hms::hms(second(df$timestamp), minute(df$timestamp), hour(df$timestamp))
```

convert to `POSIXct` again since ggplot does not work with class `hms`.

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time)


ggplot(df, aes(time)) + 
  geom_density(fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) + #also play with adjust such as adjust = 0.5
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"), labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

to plot it scaled to 1:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_density( aes(x = time, y = ..scaled..), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"), labels=date_format("%H:%M"))
```

where `..scaled..` is a computed variable for `stat_density` made during plot creation.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I'm trying to make this plot in "2 hour" break format, not dates. Basically I want to see at what time the count is high in the 24 hour period. There are the social post timestamps.

Comment: I'm sorry; perhaps, I was not fully clear on what wanted. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Great! I was able to recreate this according to your solution. One question though - why is it showing scientific numbers on y axis? I changed that by using `options(scipen=10000)`, so it shows decimal numbers now. What should I interpret from the decimal?

Comment: A density curve must be non-negative everywhere and the integral of the whole curve must be equal to one. You can also plot it scaled if you like: check edit.

Answer (score 5):

One problem with the solutions posted here is that they ignore the fact that this data is circular/polar (i.e. 00hrs == 24hrs). You can see on the plots on the other answer that the ends of the charts dont match up with each other. This wont make too much of a difference with this particular dataset, but for events that happen near midnight, this could be an extremely biased estimator of density. Here's my solution, taking into account the circular nature of time data:

```
# modified code from https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/2239

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(circular)

df = read.csv("data.csv")
datetimes = df$timestamp %>%
  lubridate::parse_date_time("%m/%d/%Y %h:%M")
times_in_decimal = lubridate::hour(datetimes) + lubridate::minute(datetimes) / 60
times_in_radians = 2 * pi * (times_in_decimal / 24)

# Doing this just for bandwidth estimation:
basic_dens = density(times_in_radians, from = 0, to = 2 * pi)

res = circular::density.circular(circular::circular(times_in_radians,
                                                    type = "angle",
                                                    units = "radians",
                                                    rotation = "clock"),
                                 kernel = "wrappednormal",
                                 bw = basic_dens$bw)

time_pdf = data.frame(time = as.numeric(24 * (2 * pi + res$x) / (2 * pi)), # Convert from radians back to 24h clock
                      likelihood = res$y)

p = ggplot(time_pdf) +
  geom_area(aes(x = time, y = likelihood), fill = "#619CFF") +
  scale_x_continuous("Hour of Day", labels = 0:24, breaks = 0:24) +
  scale_y_continuous("Likelihood of Data") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: Density Plot considering circular data]

Note that the values and slopes of the density plot match up at the 00h and 24h points.